# Is it possible to reverse the transition execution on mouse out?

Tags: css

I have two elements, the one nested inside the other. Those two elements have different transition effects applyed, and I like to have the effects order in reversed when the mouse out of the parent element.

My code looks like this:

```css
.parent {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : #AF0;
  position : relative;
  transition: background-color 0.22s ease-out;
}

.child {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 0;
  background : #0AF;
  transition: all 0.22s ease-out 1s;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color : #FA0;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background: #0FA;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

As you can see, this code, executed normally when I hover my mouse for over a second.

The problem is when mouse is out. The parent element changes color too fast, and then the child element shrink back again.

So, is there any solution to achive this effect by using CSS only ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to add a [`transition-delay`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/CSS/transition-delay) to the transitions, and make these different for normal and hover.

The child needs to wait 1s on hover but run immediately on mouseout

The parent needs to run immediately on hover but wait 1s on mouseout, so the child runs first.

```css
.parent {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : #AF0;
  position : relative;
  transition: background-color 0.22s ease-out;
  /* delay for mouseout - wait 1s for child to finish */
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.child {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 0;
  background : #0AF;
  transition: all 0.22s ease-out;
  /* delay for mouseout - run immediately */
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color : #FA0;
  /* delay for mousein - run immediately */
  transition-delay: 0s;
}

.parent:hover .child {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background: #0FA;
  /* delay for mousein - wait 1s for parent */
  transition-delay:1s;
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Check this [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dnkr4hx8/)

```css
    .parent {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background-color : #AF0;
  position : relative;
  transition: background-color 0.5s ease-out;
}

.child {
  width : 100px;
  height : 100px;
  position : absolute;
  left : 0;
  top : 0;
  background : #0AF;
  transition: all 0.22s ease-out 0.2s;
}

.parent:hover {
  background-color : #FA0;
  transition: background-color 0.22s ease-out
}

.child:hover  {
  width : 200px;
  height : 200px;
  background: #0FA;
  transition: background-color 0.50s ease-out
}
```

```html
<div class="parent">
  <div class="child">
  </div>
</div>
```

hope this helps :)